# how to give topic access to one specific user?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-security

I am collecting the data from different resources, each resource has one specific topic for each client.
I want to give the access for each user only to the corresponding topic, so they can't have access to all the topics.
I am working with Kafka 0.10 and I am using Kafka tools.
there is solution?

Comment: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kafka-authorization/

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure [Authorisation using ACL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html).

**How to enable ACL:**

In your `server.properties` file, you need to create an `Authorizer` by adding the following line:

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

Now you need to follow the docs in order to properly configure ACL based on your use cases.

**Adding ACLs**

Now once everything is in place, let's assume you have a topic called `testTopic` to which you want to grant read and write access only to user called `Bob` from a host with IP `197.5.6.1`:

```
bin/kafka-acls --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 \
 --add \
 --allow-principal User:'Bob' --allow-host '197.5.6.1' \
 --operation Read --operation Write \
 --topic testTopic \
```